# MPI_Allgather Communication Complexity

Tags: mpi, time-complexity

I need to know the communication complexity of MPI_Allgather in terms of size of array (n) and number of processors (p). I found in a presentation that the complexity is $O(\log p + n)$ but could not find any reference to cite. Can you give me some article which I can site to include the communication complexity.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the implementation. Open MPI comes with two gather-to-all algorithms that are O(log(_N_)) and two algorithms that are O(_N_), where N is the number of ranks. Then it uses heuristics to pick the best algorithm based on _N_ and the message size. See this article by Bruck _et al._: "Efficient Algorithms for All-to-all Communications in Multiport Message-Passing Systems".

Comment: Thanks, I am using OpenMPI and MPICH2, so it should help.